# Angular 5, subscribing to firebase, first element is undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

This is my firebase realtime database:
[image]

this is my typescript code, which subscribe to the database service:

```
this.afDb.list('/images/').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
  console.log(items);
});
```

but the first item on each array is empty, null, undefined. Which part i did go wrong and how to prevent it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your data under images/q13.  The keys are all numbers.  This means that the Firebase SDK is going to interpret this as an array.  Your log output confirms this - notice the square brackets around the array members.

The one thing to bear in mind is that JavaScript arrays start at 0.  This means, when Firebase converts your database contents to an array, it's going to skip 0 because you have no data at that index.  The numbers you see are always going to be their proper array index.  It's not simply going to compact the whole thing.

So, if you want an element 0 in your array, start your database keys at 0.  Otherwise, in your client code, skip that first element, expecting that there will be no 0 element.

Comment: Thanks, I renamed my images as you mentioned and it solved my problem